# Laravel error on cpanel vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

> **Warning:**
>   require(/home/user/public_html/webfolder/vendor/composer/../../app/http/helpers.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/home/user/public_html/webfolder/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php** on
>   **line 66**

I have created a custom helpers.php

My composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
        "app/http/helpers.php"
        ],  
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

My account on cpanel dont have SSH access, so I cannot run `composer dump-autoload` or any composer commands. Please help, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you send the path to the file helpers.php?

Comment: on app/http/helpers.php

Comment: Send another location of the composer.json file and structure folder "webfolder"

Comment: Its on public_html/webfolder/composer.json